Solve equations with complex variables
I want to solve an equation with real part of complex variables.
My failed code is here. Who could help me out? Thanks a lot!
n0[x_] := 1/10*Exp[(x - 5)/12] 
eq = {a == 1 - (n0[x]*L^2)/(1 - B0*L) /. L -> 1/Re[a^(1/2)]}
B0 = 2;
Solve[eq, a]

Most of problem is solved by assuming a being real, but it would cbe more complete to assume a being a complex variable. Code below does not work.
NSolve[eq, a, Complexes]

KUN

Do you assume x\[Element]Complexes?

x is real, but a is complex.  With Solve[eq, a, Reals], there is no solution of a when x>32, but it is not true.

Isn't the question a bit strange? If x is Real, then RHS of the equation will be Real. (I think it's quite obvious. ) "there is no solution of a when x>32, but it is not true." So you mean Solve has given a incorrect solution, then can you show us a counterexample? If you mean there should be solution for x>32 based on the underlying physics, then I'm afraid your equation itself (i.e. the math part) is wrong.

@xzczd that is my view FWIW. Also please note the strange condition in Nasser answer (that is not a criticism of Nasser): Exp[…]<0 as condition in a real solution.

@xzczd: That part of your comment "Isn't the question a bit strange? If x is Real, then RHS of the equation will be Real. (I think it's quite obvious. ) " was submitted after my answer.

@user64494 Yes, but to be honest I don't think we need such complicated discussion to show RHS is Real, it's just a combination of +, -, *, /, ^2 and Exp, as long as x is Real, the RHS will be Real.

@xzczd: See the addition to my answer. I considered the case of complex x, but the OP informed that x is assumed real.

If you add Reals, it works (ps changed some letters names, to make it easy to read).
Default is complex domain for Solve, and it seems to hang. When changing to Reals, it solves it.
n0[x_] := 1/10*Exp[(x - 5)/12]
B0 = 2
eq = a == 1 - (n0[x]*L^2)/(1 - B0*L) /. L -> 1/Re[a^(1/2)]
Solve[eq, a, Reals]


To remove Root, do
 Solve[eq, a, Reals] // ToRadicals


etc...

Thank you for the nice advices. Yes, most of the problem is solved! But it would be more complete to assume a being a complex variable.

Let us write down a=r*Exp[I*t] in the exponential form with r > 0 and t > -Pi && t <= Pi and substitute it in  the equation under consideration.
a == 1 - (1/10*Exp[(x - 5)/12]*L^2)/(1 - B0*L) /. L -> 1/Re[a^(1/2)] /. a -> ComplexExpand[r*Exp[I*t]] 


r Cos[t] + I r Sin[t] ==  1 - E^(1/12 (-5 + x))/( 10 (1 - 2/Re[Sqrt[r Cos[t] + I r Sin[t]]]) Re[Sqrt[r Cos[t] + I r Sin[t]]]^2)

Its clear that its RHS is a real-valued since x is assumed real. This implies Sin[t]==0, so  t==0 || t == Pi and a is a real number. Therefore, all the solutions are real. That case is considered in the @Nasser answer.
Addition. There are complex-valued solutions in the case of concrete complex-valued x. For example,
NMinimize[{Abs[r Cos[t] + I r Sin[t] - 
(1 - E^(1/12 (-5 + x))/(10 (1 - 2/Re[Sqrt[r Cos[t] + I r Sin[t]]]) 
Re[Sqrt[r Cos[t] + I r Sin[t]]]^2) /. x -> Pi - 2.3*I)]^2, 
 r >= 0 && t > -Pi && t <= Pi}, {r, t}]


{6.153*10^-19, {r -> 1.08435, t -> -0.0150735}}

produces such a solution.

I understand. Problem is solved. Thank you!

I flagged this answer. Moderators advised to make a comment. I have not down-voted this answer. The flag comment : 1. The RHS of equation is real by construction and inspection as n0(x) is real and the substituted values B0=2 and L -> Re[…] (by definition real). This point can be made as a comment. 2. The “answer” provided obfuscates the first (obvious) point by unnecessary use and the output is less comprehensible and then vacuous argument follows. 3. The “answer” is condescending in tone but lacks insight into its own vacuous nature. 4. This has received 2 votes: is this really appropriate?

@ubpdqn: See the addition to my answer.

Well, but x has been restricted to be Real in this discussion as mentioned by OP in comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/309505/solve-equations-with-complex-variables?noredirect=1#comment758522_309505

@xzczd: I added it for the completeness. BTW, NSolve fails with complex values of x.

That's expected, because there are 2 unknowns but only one equation. FindInstance will work: FindInstance[{a == 1 - (1/10*Exp[(x - 5)/12]*L^2)/(1 - B0*L) /.       L -> 1/Re[a^(1/2)] /. a -> ComplexExpand[r*Exp[I*t]] /. {      x -> Pi - 2.3*I}, r >= 0 && t > -Pi && t <= Pi}, {r, t}]

@xzczd: Thank you for your valuable comment. Moreover, L = 1/Re[    a^(1/2)]; B0 = 2; FindInstance[{a ==        1 - (1/10*Exp[(x - 5)/12]*L^2)/(1 - B0*L) /.             L -> 1/Re[a^(1/2)] /.      a -> ComplexExpand[r*Exp[I*t]] /. {x -> Pi - 2.3*I},    r >= 0 && t > -Pi && t <= Pi}, {r, t}, 3] results in {{r -> 1.08435, t -> -0.0150735}, {r -> 3.96262,    t -> -0.143575}, {r -> 434.934, t -> 2.94949}} and repeats these solutions with 30 instead of 3.
